# How to implement a physics engine to jump in game

Tags: java, game-physics

I need to use a physics engine or something similar to achieve a downward parabolic jump in the game that I have. Right now, the up arrow will just cause the character to float, but I need him to jump.

Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.EnumMap;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Level extends JPanel {
    public static String chicken = "chicken.gif";
    public static String chicken2 = "chicken2.gif";
    private static final int PREF_W = 1440;
    private static final int PREF_H = 500;
    private static final int TIMER_DELAY = 20;
    private static final String KEY_DOWN = "key down";
    private static final String KEY_RELEASE = "key release";
    public static final int TRANSLATE_SCALE = 3;
    public static final String back = "back.gif";
    public static final String corn = "corn.gif";
    private EnumMap<Direction, Boolean> dirMap = new EnumMap<Level.Direction, Boolean>(
            Direction.class);
    private BufferedImage image = null;
    private BufferedImage image2 = null;
    private BufferedImage image3 = null;
    private static int imgX = 20;
    private static int imgY = 320;
    private static Random rand = new Random();
    private static int cImgX = rand.nextInt(1420) + 10;
    private static int cImgY = 335;
    private static int cornCounter = 0;
    private static String Counter = Integer.toString(cornCounter);
    private static final Font BG_STRING_FONT = new Font(Font.SANS_SERIF,
            Font.BOLD, 32);
    private int bgStringX;

    public Level() {
        for (Direction dir : Direction.values()) {
            dirMap.put(dir, Boolean.FALSE);
        }
        try {
            File bback = new File(back);
            image2 = ImageIO.read(bback);
            File ccorn = new File(corn);
            image3 = ImageIO.read(ccorn);
            File img = new File(chicken);
            image = ImageIO.read(img);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        new Timer(TIMER_DELAY, new TimerListener()).start();

        // here we set up our key bindings
        int condition = JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW;
        InputMap inputMap = getInputMap(condition);
        ActionMap actionMap = getActionMap();
        for (final Direction dir : Direction.values()) {

            // for the key down key stroke
            KeyStroke keyStroke = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(dir.getKeyCode(), 0,
                    false);
            inputMap.put(keyStroke, dir.name() + KEY_DOWN);
            actionMap.put(dir.name() + KEY_DOWN, new AbstractAction() {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                    dirMap.put(dir, true);
                }
            });

            // for the key release key stroke
            keyStroke = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(dir.getKeyCode(), 0, true);
            inputMap.put(keyStroke, dir.name() + KEY_RELEASE);
            actionMap.put(dir.name() + KEY_RELEASE, new AbstractAction() {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                    dirMap.put(dir, false);
                }
            });
        }
        FontMetrics fontMetrics = getFontMetrics(BG_STRING_FONT);
        int w = fontMetrics.stringWidth(Counter);

        bgStringX = (PREF_W - w) / 2;
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
    }


    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

        if (image != null) {
            g.drawImage(image2, 0, 0, this);
            validate();
            g.drawImage(image3, cImgX, cImgY, this);
            validate();
            g.drawImage(image, imgX, imgY, this);
            validate();
        }

        g.setFont(BG_STRING_FONT);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g.drawString(Counter, bgStringX, 190);
    }

    private class TimerListener implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            for (Direction dir : Direction.values()) {
                if (dirMap.get(dir)) {
                    imgX += dir.getX() * TRANSLATE_SCALE;
                    imgY += dir.getY() * TRANSLATE_SCALE;

                    //System.out.println(imgY);

                    if(imgX >= 188 && imgX <= 380) {
                        if(imgY <= 190 && imgY >= 199) {
                            imgY = 194;
                        }
                    }


                    if (imgX >= (cImgX - 10) && imgX <= (cImgX + 10)) {
                        cImgX = rand.nextInt(1420) + 10;
                        repaint();
                        validate();
                        cornCounter += 1;
                        Counter = Integer.toString(cornCounter);
                        //System.out.println(cornCounter);
                        repaint();
                        validate();
                    }

                    if(imgX <= -60) {
                        imgX = 1373;
                        repaint();
                        validate();
                    }
                    else if(imgX >= 1442) {
                        imgX = 1;
                        repaint();
                        validate();
                    }


                    if(imgY >= 320) {
                        imgY = 320;
                    }
                    else if(imgY <= 1) {
                        imgY = 1;
                    }

                }
            }
            repaint();
        };
    }


    enum Direction {

        Up(KeyEvent.VK_UP, 0, -1),
        Left(KeyEvent.VK_A, -1, 0), Right(KeyEvent.VK_D, 1, 0),
        LeftA(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT, -1, 0), RightA(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT, 1, 0),
        Down(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN, 0, 1);

        private int keyCode;
        private int x;
        private int y;

        private Direction(int keyCode, int x, int y) {
            this.keyCode = keyCode;
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }

        public int getKeyCode() {
            return keyCode;
        }

        public int getX() {
            return x;
        }

        public int getY() {
            return y;
        }

    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        Level mainPanel = new Level();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Cockadoodle Duty: Awakening");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGui();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to be a little more specific. We don't feel like finishing your code in case you lost motivation.

Answer (score 0):

That would be an overkill if you just want to achieve a simple jumping motion.

```
int vy = 0; //velocity of y
//.... heres your update code:
y += vy; //y is the yposition of your image or character
vy += GRAVITY; //GRAVITY is some arbitrary positive value
//...here's your onJump method:
vy = jumpSpeed; //jumpSpeed is some arbitrary negative value
```